# Scala - Sort Strings in a List

Tags: scala, sorting

I want to code a Scala function that sorts the Strings alphabetically in a List like so:

```
sort(List("CAR", "MELON", "HOUSE"))
//> res49: List[String] = List(ACR, ELMNO, EHOSU)
```

The thing is that I have to use match/case in order to do it.

The nearest I got to a possible solution was something like this:

```
def sortMatchCase(xs: List[String]): List[String] = {
    @tailrec
    def sortMatchCaseAux(aux: String, ys: List[String]): String = ys match {
      case Nil => ""
      case x :: xs => sortMatchCaseAux(aux.sorted, xs)
    }
    sortMatchCase(xs)
}
```

However this doesn't work.

Can anyone give me a help?

Comment: What do you mean by "have to use match/case"? What are the exact requirements?

Comment: Is this a practical problem, or a training exercise, where "you MUST use match/case because this is what the instructor requires"?

Comment: I would be surprised if either of the answers (both of which basically just wrap the library `.sorted` method, as does your example) meet the requirements of your assignment.  If they do, you're just being asked to re-implement `map`, in effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I supppose it's just an exercise of developing recursive functions with tailrec (or else, `list.map(_.sorted)` would've done it).  If so, something like the following would do it:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def sortMatchCase(list: List[String]): List[String] = {
  @tailrec
  def sortMatchCaseAux(aux: List[String], l: List[String]): List[String] = l match {
    case Nil => aux
    case x :: xs => sortMatchCaseAux(x.sorted :: aux, xs)
  }
  sortMatchCaseAux(Nil, list).reverse
}

scala> sortMatchCase(List("CAR", "MELON", "HOUSE"))
res1: List[String] = List(ACR, ELMNO, EHOSU)
```

Comment: Like radumanolescu's answer, this one also helped me because it uses match/case.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to sort the characters inside each string (and then the strings as well?), like so:

```
  val list = List("CAR", "MELON", "HOUSE")
  val sortedList = list.map(s => new String(s.toCharArray.sorted)).sorted
  sortedList foreach println
```

Comment: In my specific case I didn't need the last `val sortedList = list.map(s => new String(s.toCharArray.sorted))` without the last ".sorted" but this answered what I needed.
Even though it doesn't use the match/case I could also use map.
Thank you.